# Should I catch, and rethrow an exception in this case?

Tags: .net, exception

I'm developing in the UI layer of an application and an exception is being thrown in the business layer (or lower) after I make a request.  The exception looks like the following

"System.Exception: No Data Returned at ..."

Which its obvious someone did a simple:

```
if (...Rows.Count < 1)
    throw new Exception("No Data Returned");
```

Now in my play ground, should I try to clean this up by trying to rethrow it as a custom exception I can handle specifically as so:

```
try
{
    var myBusinessObject = MyBusinessMethod();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    if (ex.Message == "No Data Returned")
    {
        throw new NoDataException(ex.Message);
    }
    else
    {
        throw;
    }
}
```

Or is there a more graceful way of handling these.

Note, I do not have the option of changing code outside of the UI layer and I do expect to run into this particular exception often.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: can't you change the underlying layers ?

Comment: I can only go as far as requesting someone else change it.

Comment: I wish I could accept multiples as the answer, but I guess I'll have to settle for the one that provides the most value in my case.

Comment: To anyone voting to close as "too localized": I think this is a good question if you interpret it as "how do I implement exception handling when using a library written by someone who did a poor job implementing exception handling".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a little subjective, but I would rather live with the ugliness of handling a `catch (Exception)` in my code than worry about what happens if someone changes the error message to something other than `No Data Returned`.

Answer (score 2):

I really think it depends on what that exception means in the context of your call. For example, if you're asking to load a customer by name or ID, the exception might simply be reported to your user with a 'customer not found' dialog. If, on the other hand, you're trying to load something critical you think *should* be there and you get that exception, you've got to do something different.

The bottom line is, it really depends on the nature and severity of the problem and what your customer expects of the UI.

Comment: I see your point, but in my case, the users do not have that much control of the application.  More clicking navigation than data entry/request.  Great answer none-the-less.

Answer (score 2):

If you cannot manage or alter code in lower levels, then you can only inform the user and invite him to retry the operation or to undertake other actions.
You don't have to display the exception message to the user (if not required). Instead, if possible, it could be useful to send a message to the business layer with information about the invoked method and the passed arguments.

Answer (score 1):

*The answer is highly specific, and depends on your requirements and the usability of your application.*

Especially at the UI layer, the answer depends significantly on what will make the application more useable, and what framework/system you have in place for handling errors.

Typically, errors that propagate this far will fall into two broad categories:

- Issues which the user should be aware of, and/or which significantly impact usability. These typically are issues where you'll want user input before deciding what action to take next (ie, if a username isn't found on login, or data that you're trying to display is unavailable). Rather than throwing a new exception, most often you're likely to report the error as appropriate for your system.
- Issues which the user should not be aware of, which are not relevant to the systems' proper functioning, or which are only relevant for system administrators etc... These types of issues are usually better handled with a rethrow of the exception, since usually you will have a top level layer which records exceptions in a place for sysadmins/etc.. to log